# How can I convert python's datetime.utcnow() to Javascript's Date.UTC?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to pass date value from Django View ( Python ) to Django template in which I'm using Javascript:

Python:

```
my_date = datetime.utcnow()  <-- output: 2019-11-12 18:23:30.239216
```

Javascript:

```
var date = new Date( Date.UTC( {{ my_date }} ) );
```

Tried this:

```
  my_date= my_date.strftime( '%Y, %m, %d' ) <-- this doesn't work correctly since Date.UTC expects month index not month number
```

How can I make the conversion and why Javascript method is using month index and not the number of the month which is more natural ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the accepted formats for Date.UTC is:

```
Example: 2019,10,14,9,0,0
```

Which represents: November 14, 2019 - 09:00:00

This can be done in Python with the following code:

```
new_date = \
        str(my_date.year) + "," + \
        str(my_date.month - 1) + "," + \
        str(my_date.day) + "," + \
        str(my_date.hour) + "," + \
        str(my_date.minute) + "," + \
        str(my_date.second)
```

Works also with IE browser.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass that string to `Date` constructor.

```js
const input = '2019-11-12 18:23:30.239216';
const jsDate = new Date(input);
console.log(jsDate); //
```

Comment: I intend to use Date.UTC which does'n work with your suggested input value.

Comment: @cristian Why do you want to use that instead of `Date.UTC()`?. Always tell what do you actually want to achieve

Comment: I want to process the date in UTC ( 0 time-offset ) rather then in local time.